# Converting NSString to std::string apostrophe character

Tags: iphone, ios, stdstring

Using `[str UTF8String]` or `[str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

The NSString:

```
Nikita's iPad
```

gives output:

```
Nikita\xe2\x80\x99s iPad
```

How do I keep it `'`?

Comment: Are you sure that's a `'` not a `’`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong apostrophe.

This:

```
[@"Nikita's iPad" UTF8String];
```

Gives the right output

This:

```
[@"Nikita’s iPad" UTF8String];
```

Gives this:

```
Nikita\xe2\x80\x99s iPad
```

You can replace the character like this:

```
NSString *new = [old stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"’" withString:@"'"];
```

Comment: what should I do if I am getting `’` from the device, instead of `'`? and what is the exact difference between the two?